# A form that writes to excel

Tags: php, c++, html, excel, forms

I was wondering what the easiest way to write a simple form program or web page that will output to a text file that can be opened in excel easily. I know how to write in C++ but I dont know any GUI and I wanted a simple form. I was thinking I could just write an HTML/PHP page but it has to be able to run without the internet, but I dont know if you can have a web page append to a file in a folder. Can anyone point me into a direction to do this?

Comment: Does it have to be an Excel sheet, or can it be something that Excel can easily import - like tab or comma delimited data?  There are many ways to do what you want, including PHP Excel libraries and [Excel XML](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-phpexcel/).  Then there's the [Office Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y1xatbkd%28VS.80%29.aspx) which can be accessed from VB.NET, C#.NET, and so on.  Can you provide a little more information about your goals?

Comment: Yes I should have specified a can just be anything that can be easily opened into excel. So even just a simple txt file that is tab delimited

Comment: I dont want anyone to write the code for me just the terminology I should look up to learn how to do this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a Windows based application, and you can code in C++, then possibly the simplest route is to get hold of Visual Studio (you can get the Express versions for free), and write something using your language of choice.

Basic GUI stuff in Visual Studio is simple enough.  You can then write your output either to a delimited text file (like a CSV), or use the [Excel Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wss56bz7%28VS.80%29.aspx) if you want to create an actual Excel spreadsheet - although that might be overkill if the data are simple.

You might find this question useful too (it's about Word documents, but some of the concepts and pitfalls are the same):

[Programmatically generating editable Word docs from ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119666/programmatically-generating-editable-word-docs-from-asp-net)

Installing PHP and creating an HTML page is perfectly possible, but it seems like a lot of effort.  You should search Stackoverflow for `PHP Excel`, as you may find some other useful stuff here.

In what environment will the form/application be run?

Answer (score 1):

PHPExcel: Create .xlsx spreadsheets using php. http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

You can make a standard HTML form and use php to generate the excel file.  However you said one of your requirements was being able to run without the internet, so unless your user has php installed this solution isn't so good for you.

As you pointed out, almost anything can be opened with Excel, so perhaps you can generate a delimited txt file using JavaScript.  That would certainly run offline and not require any additional software to be installed by the user.

Edit: Here's a link to an article about writing to files in JavaScript. Very easy if you're not looking to code an actual application and use HTML, which would have maximum machine compatibility. http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1171273&page=1

Comment: So you can output to a local file with javascript because I can work with that?